# Match a condition RegEx

Tags: javascript, regex

I need to be able to strip out a condition in a string, here it is:

```
(("${Operation}" == "Fixed") && ("-" == "-"))
```

I'd like to be able to replace `"${Operation}" == "Fixed"` with `""` or anything between () that has ${} in it. In other words if there is ${} on the left hand side of the condition I want to get rid of the condition entirely.

Comment: That's a pretty flexible description of the problem.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**In general**, a regular expression is not the right approach here.  There are lots of cases that are valid JavaScript syntax, but that won't fit nicely into a regular expression.  However, here's one way to do it:

```
var code = '(("${Operation}" == "Fixed") && (thing1 == thing2))';
code = code.replace(/"[^"]*\$\{[^}]*\}[^"]*"\s*==\s*"[^"]*"/, 'true');
```

That only handles double quotes.  If you need to handle both types of quotes, the expression will be more complicated.  If you need to handle both types of quotes **and** your strings might contain quotes, then a regular expression really isn't going to work.

If you can think of a different way to solve this problem, then you should.  For example - where does the string come from?  Can you get the data in a different format?

Also, it sounds like you're setting this string up for a call to `eval`.  That's a bad idea if it contains any kind of user input.

Comment: I am able to change the data that is being passed back and I was thinking the same thing you are. I was setting up the string to use with `(new Function(string here)())` actually. I may have to build the expression on the client end instead which is what I was originally doing unfortunatly with a performance hit... But thanks for your answer thats a monster regex

Comment: I was thinking more like return some kind of JSON data structure.  But, whatever works.

Comment: Went with a difference approach. I just returned the data in a different format. Thanks for the help though!

Answer (score 1):

This will match it

```
\([^(]*\${.*?}[^)]*\)
```

[image]

Answer (score 0):

With this regex `/^\(?[^)&]*?\${.*\)/` I successfully matched the two first lines but not the two others. Is this what you are looking for?

> (("${Operation}" == "Fixed") && ("-" == "-"))
>
> ("${Operation}" == "Fixed"))
>
> (("$Operation" == "Fixed") && ("-" == "-"))
>
> (("-" == "-") && ("${Operation}" == "Fixed"))

Answer (score 0):

Interesting, I came up with `/\(("?\${.*}"?[^)]*)\)/g`:

```
'(("${Operation}" == "Fixed") && ("-" == "-"))'.replace(/\(("?\${.*}"?[^)]*)\)/g, '("")')
```

this probably has too many `*`, but internet coding questions always seems to be a little wide open anyways.

NOTE: This was like a test in special RegExp characters, fun thanks!

And the only thing keeping that sinking ship of a Regular Expression I wrote is `[^)]*` anything just not a closing `)`